# std::vector as a global variable in Visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, vector, global-variables, stdvector

I'm making a windows form application using c++ (perhaps a foolish idea?)

and i have a few global variables:

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^  openFileDialog;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ListBox^  outputListBox;
private: bool done;
private: array<String^>^ filesList;
private: vector< FrequencyDataSet > storedModels;
```

however when i compile it it says:

```
Error   1   error C4368: cannot define 'storedModels' as a member of managed 'Project::Form1': mixed types are not supported
```

what i want to happen, is that when the application loads, a thread starts in the background and loads in the stored data models. and stores them so they can be accessed by other functions at a later stage. everything else works fine so far, just need to be able to store the models globally.

can anyone suggest an alternative to how i'm going about it?

Comment: Those aren't global variables, they're class members.  A global variable of type `std::vector` works just fine.  So does a class member of type pointer to `std::vector` (but do use a smart pointer and save yourself memory management grief).

Comment: how do i got about this? i new to this whole c++ thing and Visual c++ seems even more complex..

Comment: If you're new to C++, why are you using C++/CLI?  C# would be a lot easier, if you want to use .NET and the Visual Studio Forms Designer.  If you're trying to learn C++, stay away from C++/CLI until you learn standard C++ first.  C++/CLI is really designed for people who know C# and some C++, and have an existing C++ library they want to use inside their winforms application.

Comment: @user808359 "and Visual C++ seems even more complex". This is the case because you're not using C++, but C++/CLI, which is basically C++ for .NET and is a completely different language from standard C++.

Comment: i started with a consol based application, but required a GUI and was recomended windows forms.. Never a fan of .NET but it seemed the easiest way to get a GUI going quickly... apparantly i was wrong. Could anyone recommend an alternative to get a simple GUI created easily?

Comment: @user808359: I hear good things about `wxWindows` (also called `wxWidgets`) for simple portable GUIs in C++.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector is not a managed type. The error message is pretty clear. Instead of `vector`, use a managed collection class. `System::Collections::Generic::List<FrequencyDataSet>` is nice this time of year, I've heard.

Comment: But he doesn't want a collection of strings.

Comment: i tried:     `private: System.Collections.Generic.List< FrequencyDataSet >^ storedModels;`   however i just get the error: `Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'` and `Error 2 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int ` and `Error 3 error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'`

Comment: Sorry again, C# habits getting in the way. In C++, the namespace resolution is done via ::.

Answer (score 0):

Is `FrequencyDataSet` a native type used by some library you're using?

If not, then go with `System::Collections::Generic::List<FrequencyDataSet> storedModels` as Seva suggested.

If it is, then you need a native collection to manage your native types, and `std::vector` is a good choice.  But `std::vector` can't be directly inside your `Form`, since the .NET garbage collector will move your `Form` instances around to compact memory.  So you need to put the vector where it won't move.  One option is a real global variable:

In your header file:

```
extern std::vector<FrequencyDataSet> g_storedModels;
```

and in one .cpp file:

```
std::vector<FrequencyDataSet> g_storedModels;
```

However, if you need one copy for each instance of your Form or other class, you need to use dynamic allocation from the native heap (which won't move around) and keep a pointer.  This would work (inside your `ref class MyForm` or whatever you called it):

```
std::vector<FrequencyDataSet>* storedModels;
MyForm() : storedModels(new std::vector<FrequencyDataSet>())
{
    /* the rest of your constructor... InitializeComponents and so forth */
}
```

But this vector isn't managed by the garbage collector, now you'd need to remember to free it when your `Form` is destroyed.  A smart pointer will help with that.

```
clr_scoped_ptr<std::vector<FrequencyDataSet>> storedModels;
MyForm() : storedModels(new std::vector<FrequencyDataSet>())
{
    /* the rest of your constructor... InitializeComponents and so forth */
}
```

[See here for my `clr_scoped_ptr`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1695/2150), which you may use as long as you abide by the license in the comments.  Or you can study it to learn how to write your own.

Comment: i tried this, but i just get this error: ` Error 2 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty> *' to 'FrequencyDataSet'`
 when i run this: `FrequencyDataSet freqSet = storedModels[0];`

Comment: @user808359: Try `FrequencyDataSet freqSet = (*storedModels)[0];`.